# Python Kafka mocking return type of Kafka Consumer

Tags: python, unit-testing, apache-kafka, mocking

I want to test a script when I use `kafka-python` package. I want to test type of return object for  function

```
def _get_kafka_consumer() -> KafkaConsumer:
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVICE,
                             auto_offset_reset='earliest')
    consumer.subscribe([_KAFKA_TOPIC_INPUT])
    return consumer
```

My test class looks like

```
class TestVoiceToText(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_get_kafka_consumer_output_type(self):
        result = _get_kafka_consumer()
        self.assertIsInstance(result, KafkaConsumer)
```

and of course it does not pass because there is no Kafka Cluster running so `KafkaConsumer` cannot be created. How can I mock that returning of `KafkaConsumer(...)` is of type `KafkaConsumer` without actual need of calling the actual constructor?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem by using `patch` function from `unittest.mock` package:

```
    def test_get_kafka_consumer_output_type(self):
        with patch('voice_to_text.kafka_connector.KafkaConsumer') as kafka_consumer_class_mock:
            kafka_consumer_instance = _get_kafka_consumer()
            kafka_consumer_class_mock_instance = kafka_consumer_class_mock.return_value

            kafka_consumer_class_mock.assert_called_once()
            self.assertEquals(kafka_consumer_class_mock_instance, kafka_consumer_instance)
```

It only checks if a result of `_get_kafka_consumer()` is actually an object returned by calling a function `KafkaConsumer()`. We don't care what actually that function is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You would want the concept of `spec` in mocking. You can use `autospec` here I believe with success. Speccing will limit your mock to the original API of the object you're mocking, and allow it to pass `isinstance` tests as well. Here's the documentation on Autospeccing: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing

Here's how I'd do your test:

```
 @mock.patch('voice_to_text.kafka_connector.KafkaConsumer', autospec=True)
 def test_get_kafka_consumer_output_type(self, kafka_consumer_mock):
        kafka_consumer_instance = _get_kafka_consumer()
        
        kafka_consumer_mock.assert_called_once_with(
            bootstrap_servers=_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVICE,
            auto_offset_reset='earliest')
        kafka_consumer_mock.return_value.subscribe.assert_called_once_with(
            [_KAFKA_TOPIC_INPUT])
        kafka_consumer_mock.assert_called_once()

        self.assertEquals(kafka_consumer_mock.return_value, kafka_consumer_instance)
        self.assertIsInstance(kafka_consumer_instance, KafkaConsumer)
```